# How can I give temperature monitoring absolute priority over stress testing?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, scheduling, stress-test, prime95

I am trying to stress test my home-built NAS for cooling problems.

Since neither `stress`, nor `FIRESTARTER` nor `mprime95` look after the 
temperatures, I want to write a small script that kills all of them (ie the 
one of them I am currently running) if the temperature goes up too much:

```
sudo renice -n -20 $$; \
maxitemp=0; \
while [ $maxitemp -le 40 ]; do
sleep 1
maxitemp=$(s-tui -j | jq "[.Temp|.[]|tonumber]|max")
echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S) Maximal Temperature $maxitemp"
done; \
echo "$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S) EMERGENCY KILL BECAUSE OF HIGH TEMPERATURE" | tee -a ~/stresstest.txt; \
killall stress; \
killall FIRESTARTER; \
killall mprime
```

However, if I boot up my Ubuntu live CD, connect it to the internet, install 
s-tui and jq and mprime and run it, prime95 starts the workers and the 
computer (a laptop, since I am testing the test before really running it on 
my precious NAS) **stops responding**, I cannot cancel prime95, no mouse 
moves any more, just the optical drive goes crazy. **I have to stop it by 
pressing the power button long enough to switch the machine off.**
Even when I replace the script from above with a simple

```
sudo renice -n -20 $$; \
sleep 30; 
killall mprime
```

Why is that so? How can I give my monitoring and safety nets absolute priority 
over the stressing?

---

## Update

It turned out that priorization was not the problem but mprime using too much RAM which pushed the swap/disk cache out of the RAM what made the drive go crazy and the system unresponsive.

https://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=25429

I'll leave this question here because I think the answer of powerload79 can be very helpful to others!

Comment: I'd suggest that your NAS is already victim of a cooling problem, exceeding or crashing through the thermal limit before anything else can happen, due to a poorly fitted cooler or inadequate thermal compound. Either that or you have a power supply issue.

Comment: That instantanously? And why is the CD drive going crazy? When I run stress instead of mprime, it goes up slowly and does not have any problems. I can also cancel the tests! And it is not my NAS, it is my notebook ("laptop" in German).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot give it *absolute* priority, but you can do the following to massively maximise the relative priority of the temperature monitoring:

1) Make sure you run the stressful task at nice -n 19 to minimize it's priority, in addition to setting the priority of the monitoring process to -20.

2.1) Use cgroups to further decrease the priority of the stressful tasks:

```
# Create a user and group called idle:
adduser idle

# Create a corresponding cgroup
/bin/cgcreate -a idle:idle -t idle:idle -g cpu:idle
/bin/cgset -r cpu.shares=2 idle

# Run your stressful proccess as part of this cgroup
/bin/cgexec -g cpu:/idle /usr/bin/mprime
```

2.2) Use cgroups to further increase the priority of the monitoring tasks:

```
# Create a user and group called fast:
adduser fast

# Create a corresponding cgroup
/bin/cgcreate -a fast:fast -t fast:fast -g cpu:fast
/bin/cgset -r cpu.shares=262144 fast

# Run your minitoring proccess as part of this cgroup
/bin/cgexec -g cpu:/fast /usr/bin/my_monitoring_script
```

This will make a huge amount of difference when it comes to preventing an intensive task with interfering with other worloads. Not only will your monitoring task struggle less with getting to run, but all other regular processes will be more able to run unimpeded while the stress test still gets all of the uncontested clock cycles.

3) Use tuned-adm to set the profile to "latency-performance" if your distro ships with that tool, e.g. Fedora/CentOS/RHEL. You may have to build it yourself on Ubuntu/Debian.